# Assign value to one column of a matrix in a loop

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix

I wonder if there is a simple way to produce a list of matrices with sequential names using a "for" loop, and then give one of their columns values.

```
for(i in 1:3)
{
  assign(paste0("matrix",i), matrix(NA, nrow = 4, ncol = 6))
  assign(get(paste0("matrix",i))[,1], rep(i, 4))
}
```

In the above code, I tried to create 3 matrices matrix1, matrix2, and matrix3, whose first columns were aimed to assign the values of rep(1, 4), rep(2, 4), rep(3, 4). However, R gives an error message.

```
Error in assign(get(paste0("matrix", i))[, 1], rep(i, 4)) : 
  invalid first argument
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to make a list of matrices, I would recommend using `list`. Putting them in a real `list` and not in the main env as similarly named objects creates a lot more cohesion and makes your code easier to understand.

```
matrix_list = lapply(1:3, function(x) matrix(NA, nrow = 4, ncol = 6))
names(matrix_list) = paste('matrix', 1:3)
```

The error you see is probably because `assign` requires a `character` as input. Carefully read the docs for `assign` and `get` (and never use them again ;) ).

Comment: Thank you. Actually, my code `for(i in 1:3) {assign(paste0("matrix",i), matrix(NA, nrow = 4, ncol = 6))}` can generate 3 matrice just as your code does. My problem is that is there any way to assign the column values with variable names in each loop. Thanks again.

Comment: Also, I read the docs of `assign`,  my code `assign(get(paste0("matrix",i))[,1], rep(i, 4))` should be wrong. Thank you.